# Changing frequency of a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a difficulty in solving one Matlab problem. I want to read a wav file, Re-arrange the data so that the frequency is quadrupled and play the file. Here is my first attempt, am I doing the correct thing? Any help would be appreciated.

```
hfile = 'one.wav';         
wavwrite(y, Fs, hfile)                          
clear y Fs                                      


[y, Fs, nbits, readinfo] = wavread(hfile);     

sound(y, Fs);                                   % Play the sound & wait until it finishes

duration = numel(y) / Fs;                       % Calculate the duration
pause(duration + 2)                             % Wait that much + 2 seconds

FsQ=Fs*4;
sound(y,FsQ,nbits)
```

Comment: Aron - what do you mean by _re-arrange the data_?  There will be no change to the audio data once you have quadrupled the sample rate, only that the audio data will be played at the new rate.

Comment: Geoff, does my code above quadruple the frequency and then play the final wav file? I only need to do this. Many thanks.

Comment: Aron - your code quadruples the original sample rate of **Fs** and then will play the audio data at that new rate.